# Implementing threads in Python

Tags: python

I'm beginner student T.T

I want to implement a arithmetic calculator by writing a function to be executed by a thread.

but, error keeps popping up

please, I want to know why the error pops up

====================================================

```
import threading

def execute(number) :
    
  a = int(input('first nuber ==> '))
  b = int(input('second number ==> '))
  c = input('+, -, *, /')

  if c == '+':
    print(a + b)
  elif c == '-':
    print(a - b)
  elif c == '*':
    print(a * b)
  elif c == '/':
    print(a / b)
  else:
    print('FALSE')

    print(threading.currentThread().getName() , number)

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    for i in range(1, 10 ) :
        my_thread = threading.Thread( target=  execute , args = (i, ))
        my_thread.start()
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I tested your program, it seems like you shouldn't be using threading for this.

Comment: arithmetic operation does not work properly...

Comment: Why do you need threads?

Comment: I am learning how to implement threads

Comment: what do you think your program should do when more than one thread issues an `input`, which reads from the _single_ stream (sys.stdin) in a blocking way?
You can experience with threads, but if more than one thread uses `input` (and even `print`) you will have unexpected results - this is what you are getting there.

Answer (score 1):

You should learn about [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) and [mutual exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) before you go further into threading. Your program has a race condition where all 10 threads are competing for a single resource (user `input`/access to I/O). It is random which thread will win the race and as a result your calculator is very hard to use. I have introduced mutual exclusion here, where each thread will do all of its I/O within the exclusive region before handing off control to another thread.

```
import threading

mutex = threading.Lock()

def execute(number) :
  
  mutex.acquire()
  print(threading.currentThread().getName() , number)
  a = int(input('first nuber ==> '))
  b = int(input('second number ==> '))
  c = input('+, -, *, /')
  mutex.release()

  if c == '+':
    print(a + b)
  elif c == '-':
    print(a - b)
  elif c == '*':
    print(a * b)
  elif c == '/':
    print(a / b)
  else:
    print('FALSE')
    

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    for i in range(1, 10 ) :
        my_thread = threading.Thread( target=  execute , args = (i, ))
        my_thread.start()
```

Comment: @blackcow multithreading/concurrency is a very rich and tricky topic. You can do this, good luck!